# How can I use the QUERY() function to create subtotals for each group based on a specific column within the QUERY() function's results?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am pulling the table in the screenshot below with the following query:

=QUERY(SIPARISLER; "select C, D, E, F where G = 'KESİN' order by C DESC"; 1)

[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4lql.png)

But I want to get a subtotal based on the ORDER NO value as follows. How can I do that?

[What I want to do!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m21Se.png)

***INPUT*** (**obtained from query**):

| + | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FIRMA | ORNER NO | BCE NO | QTY |
| 2 | SLP | 231561 | 30-129 | 50 |
| 3 | SLP | 231561 | 30-302 | 30 |
| 4 | SLP | 231784 | 30-116 | 100 |
| 5 | OFM | 312 | 30-123 | 3 |
| 6 | DELTA | 233391 | 60-120 | 6 |

***EXPECTED OUTPUT***:

| + | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FIRMA | ORDER NO | BCE NO | QTY |
| 2 | SLP | 231561 | 30-129 | 50 |
| 3 | SLP | 231561 | 30-302 | 30 |
| 4 | SUBTOTAL |  |  | 80 |
| 5 | SLP | 231784 | 30-116 | 100 |
| 6 | SUBTOTAL |  |  | 100 |
| 7 | OFM | 312 | 30-123 | 3 |
| 8 | SUBTOTAL |  |  | 3 |
| 9 | DELTA | 233391 | 60-120 | 6 |
| 10 | SUBTOTAL |  |  | 6 |

Comment: [duplicate of this post here](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/1bbzd5d/how_do_i_make_a_subtotal_with_the_query_function/)

Answer (score 0):

*Here's [one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M36zsg5IAWXiUSQ8Zoc5KgKUGNZvwCp7QByb24G72qU/edit#gid=87895906) you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ;query(SIPARISLER; "select C, D, E, F where G = 'KESİN' order by C DESC";0); Λ;index(Σ;;2);
    reduce(tocol(;1);unique(Λ);lambda(a;c;vstack(a;filter(Σ;Λ=c);hstack("SUBTOTAL";;;sum(ifna(filter(index(Σ;;4);Λ=c))))))))
```

[image]